# Regular growth of ranks in Iwasawa tower

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-number-theory, group-cohomology, profinite-groups, iwasawa-theory

$\newcommand{\rank}{\operatorname{rank}}$Let $G=H \times K$ be a torsion free pro-$p$, $p$-adic Lie group. Let $H  =\mathbb{Z}_p$, the ring of $p$-adic integers and $K$ is a non-commutative torsion free pro-$p$, $p$-adic Lie group. Let $H_n=p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Let $M$ be a finitely general module over the Iwasawa Algebra $\Lambda(G)=\mathbb{Z}_p[[G]]$. Let $M_H=M/I(H)$, the co-invariance of $M$ with respect to the augmentation ideal of $I(H)$ of $H$. 
Then I want to understand whether the following two statements are equivalent.

1) $M_H$ is a $\Lambda(K)$-module of rank $r$.

2) $M_{H_n}$ is a $\Lambda(K)$-module of rank $p^nr$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

Note that $M$ is a $\Lambda(G)$ module implies that $M$ is also a $\Lambda(G_n)$ module where $G_n: =H_n \times K$ and hence $G_n$ is of finite index in $G$. Therefore, $M_{H_n}$ is also a $\Lambda(K)$-module which is in (2) above.

If (1) and (2) above are not equivalent, which one implies the other? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I know the following statement:
$\rank_{\Lambda(G)}M = [G:G_0]\rank_{\Lambda(G_0)}M$ if $G_0$ is an open normal subgroup of $G$ but this does not seem to help as, in (1) and (2),  I am interested in the ranks over the same Iwasawa Algebra but I am taking the coinvariances differently.